# Where and how to use fwrite function in c

Tags: c, structure, fwrite

I just can't understasnd how fwrite finction works in c.I had made a c program.here it it:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
struct books
{
    char name[100];
    float price;
    int pages;
}book1;

puts("enter the name of the book");gets(book1.name);
puts("enter the price of the book");scanf("%f",&book1.price);
puts("enter the pages of the book");scanf("%d",&book1.pages);

FILE *b=fopen("Book.txt","w");
fwrite(&book1,sizeof(book1),1,b);
}
```

here is input of th program:-

```
 $ ./a.out 
 enter the name of the book
 Voldemort the last BSD user
 enter the price of the book
 40000
 enter the pages of the book
 34
```

and here is the content of the file:-

```
 $ cat Book.txt 
  Voldemort the Great Linux and bsd user!����c����@�@��,B
```

Thus what is wrong in my program ? How does fwrite works ? When should I use it?

Comment: What's wrong with your program depends on what output you've expected at the first place.

Comment: You need declare variable type book1, also you forgot to close the file

Comment: well, the ����c����@�@��,B part (16 bytes) is actually your price (8 bytes) and pages data (8 bytes). You first need to understand how C/C++ manages data before diving into saving stuff to a file

Comment: Use `fprintf` instead of `fwrite` If you want to write in text to a file.

Comment: When using `fwrite/fread`, best to open the file in _binary_ mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing and reading (fwrite - fread) structures with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601816/writing-and-reading-fwrite-fread-structures-with-pointers)

Comment: I think your input and output doesn't match in this question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is immediately wrong with your program, except that you use `gets()`, which is **very wrong** (a guaranteed buffer overflow), but has nothing to do with your question, so I just leave the hint here: Use `fgets()` and for general information how to reliably get input in C, I recommend reading

- [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35178520/2371524)
- [A beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

As for your question, `fwrite()` writes whatever you give it to a file in exactly the same way it's in the memory of your computer. You could read this same file again with `fread()` and end up with the same `struct`. But **be aware** the representations of data types are *implementation defined*. So you can't for example read this file on a different machine, or even on the same machine with a program compiled using a different compiler. Therefore, using `fwrite()` to write whole `struct`s is of very limited use in practice.

As for why you see "*strange stuff*" with `cat`, that's simply because `cat` interprets all file contents as characters. You would see the same if you would just write your `float` and `int` to `stdout` directly, instead of *formatting* it with `printf()`.

To write `struct`s in a portable way to a file, you have to apply some sort of *data serialization*. A very simple way would be to use `fprintf()` with a sensible format string. There are many possibilities to do that, you could e.g. use a JSON format with an appropriate JSON library, same goes for XML.

Answer (score -2):

This is correct. The fwrite writes write file binary making the exact copy of the memory occupied by your structure in your file. If you want to save binary members / fields in the text form you need to serialize it ie convert binary data to text and write the converted ones to the file.

for example instead of `fwrite` use `fprintf`

```
  fprintf(b, "%s,%f,%d\n", book1.name, book1.price, book1.pages);
```

Comment: So `fwrite` is used for writing binary ??

Comment: @voldimot everything is binary data, "text data" is just binary data plus a given interpretation of such data

Comment: @PeterJ I think OP's fwrite solution and yours solution are both valid. What we are missing here is the format in which store such data to a file

Comment: @Gianluca Ghettini it not about the validity, but about the idea. OPs file name has the .txt extension - which usually means : text. Text means - human readable content

Comment: @voldimot Roughly yes. `fwrite` is used to write the memory content verbatim (often called binary data), `fprintf` to produce a "string" representation of the data (often called text). But Gianluca is right, in computer world, everything is binary at the end.

Comment: @PeterJ of course, but you are implicitly adding an arbitrary format: comma separated values stored in decimal as text. Perfectly fine but is this what we want? who (or what) is going to read the file?

Comment: @Gianluca Ghettini you have missed the very important word: "example".