# I send a C structure through socket but can not get it right, always miss some bytes

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Update:
I add a `while` to get the remain data, problem solved. thanks you guys.

```
while(res != rcvread->size + 4) {/* do not get full data */
    tmp = recv(connfd, (void *)rcvread + res, rcvread->size + 4 - res, 0);
    if(tmp == -1)
        printf("error:%s\n",(char *)strerror(errno));
    res+=tmp;
}
```

I want to send a structure `mfsio` through socket, the return value of `write` is 37772, but when I got it from the other program, the return value of `read` is 32768, that's really odd.

The definition of this structure is here

```
struct mfsio{
    size_t size;
    char buf[];
};
```

The send code is here

```
struct mfsio *sndread;
sndread = malloc(sizeof(struct mfsio) + rcvcmd->size);
res = pread(fd, &(sndread->buf), rcvcmd->size, rcvcmd->offset);
sndread->size = res;
res = write(connfd, sndread, sizeof(struct mfsio) + res);
```

The receive code is here

```
struct mfsio *rcvread;
rcvread = malloc(sizeof(struct mfsio) + size);
res = 0;    
res = read(connfd, rcvread, sizeof(struct mfsio) + size);
```

`size` equals to `rcvcmd->size`, and the res of `pread` is 32678, the res of `write` is 32772.
but res of `read` is 32678.

How can such thing happened? Does I do something wrong here?

**If there is no input from `write`, the `read` function will just waiting for some data and just hanging there**

**If I use a loop to avoid such problem, how can I finally get the entire data structure, I mean if I do loop reading, I will get the remain bytes from the socket, but how can I combine these clips I get?**

Comment: You have to adjust the pointer where you read into as part of the loop, add to it the number of bytes you previously read. Make sure you are using a char pointer for this pointer arithmetic though.

Comment: struct packings are not portable. You need to send a serialized representation of the data.

Comment: @kaizer.se So is there any lib on linux can do that? I've done some google search, but not find one.

Comment: @bxshi: see http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libpack/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371371/serialize-data-structures-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do your reads and writes in a loop until all of the expected data is read/written. For the read, you have to read until it returns 0, indicating nothing else is available. Or -1 indicating an error.

Your more recent problem is that you are using pointer arithmetic with your struct pointer:

```
tmp = recv(connfd, rcvread + res, rcvread->size + 4 - res, 0);
```

In C when you do pointer arithmetic you are not working with bytes, but you are working with the size of the object (rvcread for example). You should define a `char *` which is the byte location of where you will read into and then update this as you read through the data.

Comment: I want to get this structure. If I use a loop, then I could only get the left bytes, but not the entire structure. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: I think you would better receive all of data by loop statement just like above Upton's answer.

Comment: I add these code to get the remain data, but it returns a `Bad address`.  while(res != rcvread->size + 4){/* do not get full data */
  tmp = recv(connfd, (void *)(rcvread + res), rcvread->size + 4 - res, 0);
  if(tmp == -1)
   printf("error:%s\n",(char *)strerror(errno));
  res+=tmp;
 }`

Comment: If you still having trouble, can you  edit your original post to show the code you are now using that does not work? I can't really see what you are doing from the code in a comment, it's too hard to read.

Comment: I expanded my answer to hopefully address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`read` and `write` operate on byte streams. There is no guaranty that read will read as many bytes as write wrote to it. Either use sendmsg or put record sizes or record separators into the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Francis Upton's answer seems like the right one, you should certainly follow his advice.
But I have another guess, maybe it's the problem.
You don't show how you get the value of size in the receiver. A reasonable way to do it would be to read 4 bytes from the socket into size. So if you did that, you already read 4 bytes, and will get 4 bytes less in the next read.

Comment: I just read the max possible size of bytes from my receiver, and the data equals or less than that size.

Comment: @bxshi: That concept will not work. The sender needs to supply the _actual_ size written, otherwise you cannot determine on the reader side how many bytes to read.

Answer (score 0):

The flag `MSG_WAITALL` on `recv()` might also be of interest, as it basically does the whole

```
 while (!allDataReceived) {
   receiveMoreData();
 }
```

thing for you.

However, the other answers hinting you that you should send a header with "this is how many bytes will follow" are definitely something you should listen to as well.