# Adding structure to an array of char in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a C program that receives a 64 byte array of char (which is passed via USB).  Depending on the first byte (which indicates the command type) I want to 'impose' a structure over the char array to make the code clearer.

For example, if the command code is 10 I would expect something like:

```
struct
{
    uint8_t commandNumber;
    uint16_t xPos;
    uint16_t yPos;
    int32_t identificationNumber;
 } commandTen;
```

So I would like to cast my char packet[64] 'onto' commandTen and then access the fields using something like:

```
localVar = commandTenPacket->xPos;
```

How can this be achieved in C?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're gonna need to "pack" the struct to get rid of the alignment padding.

Comment: This can't be done portably.  You would probably be better off reading the bytes and building the values from the bytes directly.

Comment: Sounds to me like keyword `union` will go a long way towards handling this.

Comment: You might find this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/371371/951890

Comment: Perhaps I should add that the code is intended for a very resource limited AVR microcontroller so portability is less important that saving RAM.  Since I have the 64 byte buffer I am looking for a way to access it in a more readable manner without using any more RAM if possible (which is why using a library or copying to local variables is undesirable).

Comment: ...and don't forget about if there is and endianess you need to lookout for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, as others said you'd have to ensure that your `struct` has no padding. Your compiler probably has an extension for that, `#pragma pack` or so.

Define a `struct` for each of your use cases, not a variable as in your example.

Then define a `union`

```
typedef union overlay overlay;

union overlay {
 uint8_t raw[64];
 struct type10 command10;
 struct type42 command42;
};
```

Now create a buffer of that type

```
overlay buffer;
```

Feed the "raw" part to your function that receives the data: `getit(buffer.raw)`. And then

```
switch (buffer.raw[0]) {
 case 10: {
   // use buffer.command10
   break;
 }
 case 42: {
   // use buffer.command42
 }
}
```

This is guaranteed by the C standard to work well, since you are reading everything as `uint8_t` AKA `unsigned char`. In fact, the principle use case for `union`s is just this sort of "type puning". The whole network layer with it different types of IPv4, IPv6 etc addresses works in a similar way.

Comment: You could also add the `uint8_t` with the command code to the `union` directly; it could be a bit more elegant checking that way.

Comment: @MichałGórny, yes, but these things then are really a question of taste. I personally would prefer to always "see" `raw[0]` to be reminded that there is a byte transfer somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Don't cast. Use `memcpy`

```
char packet[64];
...

assert(sizeof commandTen <= sizeof packet);
memcpy(&commandTen, packet, sizeof commandTen);
```

This assumes that the sizes and memory layouts match properly (the same assumption a cast-based solution would use).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using pointers. Let me try to explain it this way:

```
struct commandX {
   int x;
};
struct commandMessage {
   char[8] msg;
};

char* message = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*9); // this will allow us a struct 
                                                // size of 8 bytes, since the
                                                // first byte will store the
                                                // information on how to inter-
                                                // the memory (or you do it in
                                                // a different way).
// 1. determine your offset
//    in this case, it would be the length of the command on how to interpret.
//    basically, it has to be the count of bytes from the
//    beginning of your message to the start of your struct
int offset = sizeof(char) * 1;
// 2. read the command (that would be: message[0])
// 3. now get rid of the type information, so that you can address every byte
void* temp = (void*) message;
// 4.1 if it is commandX:
struct commandX *x_temp = (struct commandX*) (temp+offset);
    // use x_temp->x
// 4.2 if it is commandMessage:
struct commandMessage *msg_temp = (struct commandMessage*) (temp+offset)
   // use msg_temp->msg
```