# How to correctly inherit my class from istream, ostream?

Tags: c++

Well, in general, the goal is such that in the function it is possible to transfer either the object of my class, or cout | cin.

```
MyStream mout = MyStream();
MyStream min = MyStream();
...
static int UShowTFileList(ostream& out, istream& in);
...
UShowTFileList(cout, cin);
UShowTFileList(mout,min);
```

The obvious solution does not work. There are no constructors.

```
class MyStream : public ostream, public istream {...}
...
MyStream mout = MyStream();
MyStream min = MyStream();
...
-->
Error (active)  E1790   the default constructor of "MyStream" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

Well, all the challenges, too.

```
mout << "Hello, world!" << "\n";
->
Error   C2280   'MyStream::MyStream(const MyStream &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

In general, how correctly to inherit istream, ostream?
[MyStream.h](https://pastebin.com/uikz28Ut)

Comment: You don't need to inherit from std::ostream for that. You usually overload the function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyType const& m);`

Comment: This post may be of use for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720431/what-is-the-c-c-equivalence-of-java-io-serializable/37721075#37721075

Comment: @Galik Normal overloading works. I can then use the constructor, work with my "mout", "min" as well as with standard threads. But in order to pass them as parameters, as well as standard streams, my thread must be inherited.

Comment: @Galik * Inherited from them or from the base_stream...

Comment: _"`MyStream mout = MyStream();`"_ Pretty sure you just meant `MyStream mout;` And, instead of lots of `...` that could represent almost anything, show your _actual_ [mcve].

Comment: You probably don't want to inherit from `istream` or `ostream` at all. If your class is a new data source, you should be subclassing `streambuf`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are encountering is there is no nullary constructor for either `std::istream` nor `std::ostream`, they both require a `std::streambuf*` parameter. Therefore `Mystream` can't have a defaulted constructor, you will have to write one. `std::fstream` and `std::stringstream` do this with related subclasses of `std::streambuf`, `std::filebuf` and `std::stringbuf`. I suggest that you provide a streambuf subclass also.

Note that you may as well inherit from `std::iostream`, which is already a combined input/output stream. Note also that all of these names I have mentioned are type aliases for `std::basic_*<char, std::char_traits<char>>`, you can easily generalise to `template <Char = char, Traits = std::char_traits<Char>> class MyStream : std::basic_iostream<Char, Traits>{ ... }`