# Generating C data structures from IDL

Tags: c, xml, idl

I am working to create a framework in "C" language where all data structures (both standard and custom one) used in a program are auto generated from a "IDL" or "XML" file rather than hardcoded by the user.

I want to autogenerate dump functions for these data structures rather than add printf functions for each every variable whenever it is added. This is similar to CORBA functionality and I am no expert in it.

Is there any library or simplified implementation available for reference ?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371371/serialize-data-structures-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MartinBroadhurst. But the link which you have shared talks about serialization/deserlization problem right ? In my case I want to autogenerate the C structures which I use in my program so that I can also autogenerate code to dump the respective C data structures whenever I need to rather than manually write a printf for the same.

Comment: Maybe something like gSOAP? https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

Comment: Eventhough I am not looking for SOAP option I will look into gSOAP. Thanks @MartinBroadhurst